# SceneKit: programmatically subdivide materials of 3D model loaded from OBJ file?

Tags: 3d, geometry, scenekit, blender, mesh

Is it possible to programmatically subdivide materials of a model loaded from OBJ files?

Take this file for instance: https://poly.google.com/view/cKryD9VnDEZ

In SceneKit, is it possible to programmatically divide the "leg" material into two different materials, one for the thigh and one for the calf, such that you could have a red calf and a yellow thigh? And more generally, could you subdivide the leg into N different materials?

It seems possible to add materials inside of 3D modeling software like Blender, but is it possible to do so programmatically within SceneKit?

Comment: I would assign two (or more) materials to the leg in blender before exporting it. You may use the same material data for both so it starts looking all the same, but having them assigned you can just switch what material is used. Another option is using an image texture, you can swap or mix images to alter the appearance in game. Either option would be easier than programmatically choosing which faces to alter material or altering uv co-ords. Note that one material is assigned to a face, using image textures allows you to change colour mid face.

Comment: @sambler how would assigning 2+ materials help if they're both assigned to the same mesh (i.e., both assigned to the leg)? thanks!

Comment: You can assign a [different material to each face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/516/935). The faces at the top of the leg can use a blue material while the faces at the bottom can use a red material. At runtime you can change the colour of each material without altering any mesh data.

Comment: @sambler thanks for the link. we saw that, but the problem is how to select a subface inside blender? each time we select a face (e.g., leg), it selects a whole group instead of one face. even in the example you linked to, the user is selecting multiple faces -- not a single one.

Comment: If only [face select](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/introduction.html) is enabled then you can select one face at a time. Holding Ctrl/Alt/Shift will extend what is selected in different ways.

Comment: @sambler we tried that in blender but it didn't seem to work. (look at the link  here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99203/turn-faces-of-obj-mesh-into-their-own-meshes?noredirect=1#comment175608_99203). it keeps selecting a group of faces anytime you select one. perhaps you could add as an answer on that question, so we can give you credit once we solve it.